# creating a php file that displays xml values

Tags: php, xml

I have my xml file which works perfectly and is displaying correctly, now I am creating a php program that will allow ease to update it quickly and efficiently, here is my php script right now. MY PROBLEM: IT shows only one record currently in each set, it doesnt show the entire record. Below my php is a small sample of xml file.  Thanks! Here is a sample http://codepad.viper-7.com/7RznW7

```
<?php 
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->load( 'menu-1a.xml' ); 


$allmenu = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "menu" ); 
foreach( $allmenu as $themenu ) 
    {
    $head = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "menuhead" ); 
    $menuhead = $head->item(0)->nodeValue; 

            $menunames = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "menuname" ); 
            $menuname = $menunames->item(0)->nodeValue; 

            $desc= $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "menudesc" ); 
            $menudesc= $desc->item(0)->nodeValue; 

            $price = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "price" ); 
            $price = $price->item(0)->nodeValue; 

            $info2 = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "price2des" ); 
            $price2des = $info2->item(0)->nodeValue; 

            $cost2 = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "price2" ); 
            $price2 = $cost2->item(0)->nodeValue; 

            echo " <h3>$menuhead</h3><b>$menuname - $menudesc - $price -     $price2des - $price2 \n</b><br>";

    }
?>
```

--XML FILE--

```
<main>
    <menu id="appet">
    <menuhead>
    Appetizers
    </menuhead>
    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Cheese Stick
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        (6 Sticks)
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $7
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>
```

--NEW CODE! WORKS --
        load( 'menu-1a.xml' );

```
$allmenu = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "menu" ); 
foreach( $allmenu as $themenu ) {
$head = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "menuhead" ); 
$menuhead = $head->item(0)->nodeValue; 
print "$menuhead";
foreach ($themenu->getElementsByTagName('menuitem') as $menuitem) {
    $menuname = $menuitem->getElementsByTagName( "menuname" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $menudesc = $menuitem->getElementsByTagName( "menudesc" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price = $menuitem->getElementsByTagName( "price" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price2des = $menuitem->getElementsByTagName( "price2des" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price2 = $menuitem->getElementsByTagName( "price2" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    print "<b>$menuname - $menudesc - $price -     $price2des - $price2 \n</b><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over the `<menuitem>`s too inside the "menu" loop, and search for the individual `<menuitem>`'s childnodes for prizes and such. Something like this:

```
foreach( $allmenu as $themenu ) {
    $head = $themenu->getElementsByTagName( "menuhead" ); 
    $menuhead = $head->item(0)->nodeValue; 
    print $menuhead;
    foreach ($themenu->getElementsByTagName('menuitem') as $menuitem) {
        $menuname = $menuitem->getElementsByTagName( "menuname" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
        // ... the others
        print <b>$menuname - $menudesc - $price -     $price2des - $price2 \n</b><br>";
    }
```

Comment: I got one other question for ya, I added <div id=$menu> to my print $menuhead ?? It doesnt create a div with id attribute in the xml. How do i go about adding this?

Comment: I'm not sure what is in the `$menu` variable, so i just only assume that its a `DOMNode` instance, and those don't convert to strings automatically so you cant just print them. I think you wanted to do `$themenu->getAttribute('id')` there.

Answer (score 0):

It only shows one entry per each section because you have written the code that way.

You *always* access the first element only, like in `$menunames->item(0)`.

If you instead access *all* child elements - not only the first one - and you output them, your problem is solved.

Please see [`DOMElement::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/domelement.getElementsByTagName), it contains an example how you can do that.